# Library for C++ File Upload/Download?

Tags: c++

Is there a C++ library that provides functions for uploading/downloading files over http without having to deal with sockets etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [cURLpp](http://curlpp.org/) (formerly *cURL++*), the official C++ binding to [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). [Here's an example of downloading from a URL and outputting to standard out.](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/47-example-00)

Answer (score 6):

Not quite C++, but [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) is a very popular and widely used HTTP client library.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at https://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/, it has lovely REST-full support for uploading single/multiple files. An example can be found at https://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/wiki/ExampleRestController.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cURL:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Answer (score 0):

Look at SFML. It is **very easy** to use and it has support for both HTTP and FTP connections.

► http://www.sfml-dev.org/

It's mainly intended for game development, but it can be used for other things as well.